# cannot resolve symbol execute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have error like cannot resolve symbol `execute`

I am calling `execute()` method of `AsyncTask` class
I have tried modifying parameters but it's not working

code:

```
LoadImageFromURL loadImage = new LoadImageFromURL();
loadImage.execute();
```

Class:

```
private class LoadImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Integer ,Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlFlag);
                InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                return bitMap;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            iv.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
}
```

Comment: add string param to execute() mth.

Comment: Ya @ρяσѕρєя K you are right.

Comment: You must have to read first that what params does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify below code -

```
1. private class LoadImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Integer ,Bitmap> {
2. protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
```

to

```
1. private class LoadImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer ,Bitmap> {
2. protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
```

Comment: Or just pass empty String like `loadImage.execute("");`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK If i did't pass anything in `execute()` ,It will work or not?

Comment: Because I used many time `execute()` without pass anything as a parameter.

Comment: @ParsaniaHardik Post your java file code here.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani: i just suggested another way, you are right `execute()` will also work

Comment: you are right kevz  problem was that it needed void instead of string because it was not using parameter in doInBackground

Comment: @Parsania Hardik: glad it help you buddy. Plz Accept it :)